# Django - User can upload an image, but the image does not display - HTML issue? (Beginner help)

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

I'm new to Django and creating a way for users to upload an image onto a post. Then the image should be visible on each individual post's page.

So far in my 'create' function users can successfully create a post and upload a photo. The photo is uploaded into my project but it is still not displaying at all. Any help is greatly appreciated.

I think the issue is how the class in views.py, and the html in index.html is written. Just not sure how to fix.

views.py to create the post:

```
def create(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        context = {
            'form': CreateForm(),
            'form1': CategoryForm(),
            'img_form': ImgForm(),
        }
        return render(request, "auctions/create.html", context)
    else:
        form = CreateForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        form1 = CategoryForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        img_form = ImgForm(request.POST, request.FILES)

        if form.is_valid():
            title = form.cleaned_data['title']
            description = form.cleaned_data['description']
            starting_bid = form.cleaned_data['starting_bid']
        if form1.is_valid():
            category = form1.cleaned_data['category']
        if img_form.is_valid():
            image = img_form.cleaned_data['image']

            auctionCreated = Listings.objects.create(
                title=title,
                description=description,
                starting_bid=starting_bid,
            )
            categoryCreated = Categories.objects.create(
                category=category,
            )
            ImageCreated = Img.objects.create(
                image=image,
            )
            return redirect('index')
```

views.py - this should show a list of each post (on the homepage) and each image should be visible but the image is not appearing:

```
def index(request):
    items = Listings.objects.all()
    images = Img.objects.all()
    return render(request, "auctions/index.html", {
        'items': items,
        'images': images,
    })
```

views.py to display image:

```
class ImgDisplay(DetailView):
    model = Img
    template_name = 'listing.html', 'index'
    context_img_name = 'pic'
```

models.py

```
class Img(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/')
```

forms.py

```
class ImgForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Img
        fields = '__all__'
```

index.html

```
    {% for i in items %}
        {% for photo in images %}
        <img src="{{pic.image.url}}" class="card-img" alt="...">
        {% endfor %}

          <a href="{% url 'listingpage' i.id %}"><button class="btn btn-primary">Bid Now! 
     </button></a>

     {% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your index.html parameters are not correct. you are passing `images` as context parameter from `index view`. But when you are using `for-loop` in index.html you are using `pic.image.url` as a image source which should be `photo.image.url`.

if you want to show images by using `ImgDisplay(DetailView)` then you can use `pic.image.url` and also need to correct the `template_name`.

```
`template_name` = 'listing.html', 'index.html'
```